# Actionscript equivalent to PHP's create_function()

Tags: php, actionscript, create-function

I was wondering if actionscript had something equivalent to PHP's [create_function](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php). Specifically, the ability to create a function **from a string** is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActionScript 3 does not natively support an eval() function (which is what you're looking for), but there are several libraries which provide it.

D.eval - http://www.riaone.com/products/deval/
AS3 Eval Library - http://eval.hurlant.com/